# Newtonsoft JSON DeserializeObject Deserialization of Serialized object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON string being returned that I am trying to deserialize, but I am having problems with it filling in the values for the properties on the object.

Here is the JSON string being returned back:

```
"{\"ClientData\":[{\"clientID\":9999999,\"userID\":123,\"authID\":\"8a20627be9ec4c608f4c609a24e74174\"}]}"
```

Now, I have my ClientData class specified via the following:

```
public class ClientData
{
    [JsonProperty("clientID")]
    public long? ClientID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userID")]
    public int? UserID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("authID")]
    public string AuthID { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here in the conversion?  I thought it would be as simple as specifying:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientData>(auth);
```

However, this doesn't yield any results.  I think the problem may be how the JSON string is being constructed, i.e. the properties defined for the object.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: In your JSON, ClientData is an array (collection) not a single object but you're deserializing as though it is a single object.  the "[]" is dead giveaway

Comment: It bombs if I use the <List<ClientData>> though?  I thought that may have been it as well, but using List doesn't work either.  It states "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AerosExpress.Adjuster.Demo.DataClasses.ClientData]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly."

Comment: Create a Top level class that has 1 property which is a list<ClientData> and serialize to that top level class.

Comment: if you change your class to public class SomeClass { public List<ClientData> ClientData {get;set;}}.  And Do <SomeClass>, you should get the object

Comment: Ah okay, you think that would be better or that it would be better to change the serialization of the object?  I was serializing from a DataTable representing the class from the database side, but in this case it should only ever yield the 1 result.

Comment: Are the embedded quotes in your JSON string really escaped as you show?  I.e does the JSON contain `\"ClientData\"` or `"ClientData"` ?

Comment: @NathanRaley with what you've provided so far I'd change serialization

Comment: They were pasted as returned from the visualizer for the string property after fetching the JSON string.  I think it may make sense in this case as Leo mentioned to reformat them for ones that return a single object.  We had originally formatted it that was so that all the items were parsed the same way, be it from a list or single.  However, that was also being converted to a dictionary and manually parsing in iOS and objective C and not .NET.  I think .NET being able to handle that for us is worth the restructure of the helper methods to return a single item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you have is a JSON array wrapped inside another object. You need to create a secondary class, place your `ClientData` as a list inside that one and deserialize that it.

**Base class that contains your list**

```
public class ClientDataInformation 
{
    [JsonProperty("ClientData")]
    public List<ClientData> ClientList {get;set;}
}
```

**Deserialization**

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientDataInformation>(auth);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the problem

```
private static clientFileName = "yourfile.dat";

public static async Task<List<ClientData>> LoadClientDataFromJsonAsync()
    {
        string clientJsonString = await DeserializeClientDataAsync(clientFileName);
        if (clientJsonString != null)
            return (List<ClientData>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(clientJsonString, typeof(List<ClientData>));
        return null;
    }

private static async Task<ClientData> DeserializeClientDataAsync(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(localFile);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I wish it was as easy as recasting like that, but alas it complains about that one as well.  Thanks for the recommendation Kasper.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your client data is set as an array. Remove the brackets and see if that works. Also, you have it wrapped in another class. If you need the prefaced ClientData, you'll need some kind of class like:

```
public class ClientDataObject
{
    public ClientData ClientData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: From what I've read from the other suggestions it would need to be a list of ClientData not just a singleton.  Other than that, it was in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that since there was no list/array in the existing code, that the JSON must have been wrong.

Comment: No, I tried converting it to a List<ClientData> in the DeserializeObject call, but it didn't like the format of that either and threw a JSON deserialization error.  However, your suggestion about removing the square brackets suggestion was valid, as that would remove the collection and wouldn't require a wrapper to correctly deserialize the object.